# Variable not defined in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I keep running into an error with AMPL wherein whenever I try to model my mod file I get an error: Y1 is already defined, this is first time I am using AMPL and not sure where I am going wrong, following is my code and I would really appreciate any help with this. I tried changing the variable name from Y1 to something else then I started getting same error with other variable:

```
#Creating Variables
var Y1;
var Y2;
var Y3;
#writing the objective fincations
maximize Throughput:500 * Y1 + 450 * Y2 + 600 * Y3;
#writing constraints
subject to 1_limit: 8 * Y1 + 5 * Y2 + 8 * Y3 <=60;
subject to 2_limit: 10 * Y1 + 20 * Y2 + 10 * Y3 <=150;
subject to 3_limit: 0 <= Y1 <=8;
```

Comment: It works for me, I get an optimal OF=4,909
How are you running it? Typing solve; in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Put the line `reset;` at the front of your program.

AMPL remembers code previously run, and is getting confused because it remembers that you have already defined `Y1`.